# How can i get information in between the indexes using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

1. Icing of the engine and the leading edges of the intake duct can occur during flight through clouds containing supercooled water droplets or during ground operation in freezing fog. Protection against ice formation may be required since icing of these regions can considerably restrict the airflow through the engine, causing a loss in performance and possible malfunction of the engine. Additionally, damage may result from ice breaking away and being ingested into the engine or hitting the acoustic material lining the intake duct.  147   2. An ice protection system must effectively prevent ice formation within the operational requirements of the particular aircraft. The system must be reliable, easy to maintain, present no excessive weight penalty and cause no serious loss in engine performance when in operation. 3. Analyses are carried out to determine whether ice protection is required and, if so, the heat input required to limit ice build up to acceptable levels. Fig. 13-1 illustrates the areas of a turbo-fan engine typically considered for ice protection. 4. There are two basic systems of ice protection; turbo-jet engines generally use a hot air supply (fig. 13-2), and turbo-propeller engines use electrical power or a combination of electrical power and hot   Ice protection  Fig. 13-1  Areas t picall considered for ice protection.  Fig. 13-  Hot air ice protection.  148  149    Ice protection air. Protection may be supplemented by the circulation of hot oil around the air intake as shown in fig. 13-3. The hot air system is generally used to prevent the formation of ice and is known as an anti- icing system. The electrical power system is used to break up ice that has formed on surfaces and is known as a de-icing system. HOT AIR SYSTEM 5. The hot air system provides surface heating of the engine and/or powerplant where ice is likely to form. The protection of rotor blades is rarely necessary, because any ice accretions are dispersed by centrifugal action. If stators are fitted upstream of the first rotating compressor stage these may require  149   Ice protection protection. If the nose cone rotates it may not need anti-icing if its shape, construction and rotational characteristics are such that likely icing is acceptable. 6. The hot air for the anti-icing system is usually taken from the high pressure compressor stages. It is ducted through pressure regulating valves, to the parts requiring anti-icing. Spent air from the nose cowl anti-icing system may be exhausted into the compressor intake or vented overboard.

How can I use regex to get 1. , 2.  ... I tried using this but to no avail ^\d..*(?=\d.), it gives me everything

Comment: The question is not very clear but perhaps you're looking for `\d\..*?(?=\d\.|$)`? See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/f37tPX/1).

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d+\..*?(?=\d+\.|\Z)', txt)`

Comment: hi @41686d6564, yes that is what im looking for. May I know what is the purpose of the ```|``` and how can I get all of them instead of only the first one ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, but it captures everything

Comment: @user13883454 It's called OR and it's used for [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). _"how can I get all of them instead of only the first one"_ - If you're using `findall`, it should indeed return all of them. On another note, Wiktor's pattern might be better than mine in two ways. 1) `\d+` will match one _or more_ digits, not just one (you decide which works best for you). 2) `\Z` will assert position at the _very_ end of the string by default, while by default, `$` asserts position at the end of the _line_.

Comment: No, it matches what you need - https://regex101.com/r/zyYsyo/1. `\d\..*?(?=\d\.|$)` will fail in case the bullet points are 2-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<!-)\d+\..*?(?=(?:$|[^-]\d+\.))
```

1. `(?<!-)\d+\.` Matches Number followed by '.' that is not preceded by '-' (so that we don' match 'fig. 13-3.')
2. `.*?` Non=greedily matches characters until ...
3. `(?=(?:$|[^-]\d+\.))` ... we see either the end of string or we see the start of the next match.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3VkfbO/1/)

The code:

```
import re

s = """1. Icing of the engine and the leading edges of the intake duct can occur during flight through clouds containing supercooled water droplets or during ground operation in freezing fog. Protection against ice formation may be required since icing of these regions can considerably restrict the airflow through the engine, causing a loss in performance and possible malfunction of the engine. Additionally, damage may result from ice breaking away and being ingested into the engine or hitting the acoustic material lining the intake duct.  147   2. An ice protection system must effectively prevent ice formation within the operational requirements of the particular aircraft. The system must be reliable, easy to maintain, present no excessive weight penalty and cause no serious loss in engine performance when in operation. 3. Analyses are carried out to determine whether ice protection is required and, if so, the heat input required to limit ice build up to acceptable levels. Fig. 13-1 illustrates the areas of a turbo-fan engine typically considered for ice protection. 4. There are two basic systems of ice protection; turbo-jet engines generally use a hot air supply (fig. 13-2), and turbo-propeller engines use electrical power or a combination of electrical power and hot   Ice protection  Fig. 13-1  Areas t picall considered for ice protection.  Fig. 13-  Hot air ice protection.  148  149    Ice protection air. Protection may be supplemented by the circulation of hot oil around the air intake as shown in fig. 13-3. The hot air system is generally used to prevent the formation of ice and is known as an anti- icing system. The electrical power system is used to break up ice that has formed on surfaces and is known as a de-icing system. HOT AIR SYSTEM 5. The hot air system provides surface heating of the engine and/or powerplant where ice is likely to form. The protection of rotor blades is rarely necessary, because any ice accretions are dispersed by centrifugal action. If stators are fitted upstream of the first rotating compressor stage these may require  149   Ice protection protection. If the nose cone rotates it may not need anti-icing if its shape, construction and rotational characteristics are such that likely icing is acceptable. 6. The hot air for the anti-icing system is usually taken from the high pressure compressor stages. It is ducted through pressure regulating valves, to the parts requiring anti-icing. Spent air from the nose cowl anti-icing system may be exhausted into the compressor intake or vented overboard."""

l = re.findall(r'(?<!-)\d+\..*?(?=(?:$|[^-]\d+\.))', s)
for item in l:
    print("Item:", item)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Item: 1. Icing of the engine and the leading edges of the intake duct can occur during flight through clouds containing supercooled water droplets or during ground operation in freezing fog. Protection against ice formation may be required since icing of these regions can considerably restrict the airflow through the engine, causing a loss in performance and possible malfunction of the engine. Additionally, damage may result from ice breaking away and being ingested into the engine or hitting the acoustic material lining the intake duct.  147

Item: 2. An ice protection system must effectively prevent ice formation within the operational requirements of the particular aircraft. The system must be reliable, easy to maintain, present no excessive weight penalty and cause no serious loss in engine performance when in operation.

Item: 3. Analyses are carried out to determine whether ice protection is required and, if so, the heat input required to limit ice build up to acceptable levels. Fig. 13-1 illustrates the areas of a turbo-fan engine typically considered for ice protection.

Item: 4. There are two basic systems of ice protection; turbo-jet engines generally use a hot air supply (fig. 13-2), and turbo-propeller engines use electrical power or a combination of electrical power and hot   Ice protection  Fig. 13-1  Areas t picall considered for ice protection.  Fig. 13-  Hot air ice protection.  148  149    Ice protection air. Protection may be supplemented by the circulation of hot oil around the air intake as shown in fig. 13-3. The hot air system is generally used to prevent the formation of ice and is known as an anti- icing system. The electrical power system is used to break up ice that has formed on surfaces and is known as a de-icing system. HOT AIR SYSTEM

Item: 5. The hot air system provides surface heating of the engine and/or powerplant where ice is likely to form. The protection of rotor blades is rarely necessary, because any ice accretions are dispersed by centrifugal action. If stators are fitted upstream of the first rotating compressor stage these may require  149   Ice protection protection. If the nose cone rotates it may not need anti-icing if its shape, construction and rotational characteristics are such that likely icing is acceptable.

Item: 6. The hot air for the anti-icing system is usually taken from the high pressure compressor stages. It is ducted through pressure regulating valves, to the parts requiring anti-icing. Spent air from the nose cowl anti-icing system may be exhausted into the compressor intake or vented overboard.
```

If you didn't care about the section numbers, you could just split the text thus:

```
l = re.split('(?<!-)\d+\. ', s)[1:]
```

Or if you knew the section numbers were numbered consecutively starting with 1:

```
l = re.split('(?<!-)\d+\. ', s)[1:]
for i, item in enumerate(l):
    print(f'{i + 1}. {item}')
    print()
```